# ng-disabled not working on $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a table with rows that correspond to pipelines a user has created. There is an option to start or stop that pipelines. If a pipeline is running, the corresponding "Start" Button should be disabled, as well as if a pipeline is getting started right now (before the success function of the startPipeline ajax call gets fired). So, whenever a user clicks "start" I set a scope variable starting to true, which should disable the start button until it gets re-enabled in the success function. But ng-disabled doesn't seem to work. Part of my html (starting part, stopping is the same):

```
<tr ng-repeat="pipeline in pipelines" ng-click="showPipeline(pipeline)" >
                        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                        <td>{{pipeline.name}}<br/>{{pipeline.description}}</td>
                        <td>TBD</td>
                        <td>{{pipeline.running == true ? 'Running' : 'Idle'}}</td>
                        <td><md-button  ng-click="startPipeline(pipeline._id)" class="md-icon-button md-raised" ng-disabled="starting || pipeline.running == true">
```

and the important parts of my Controller:

```
$scope.starting = false;
$scope.stopping = false;
$scope.startPipeline = function(pipelineId) {
        $scope.starting = true;
        console.log("starting pipeline");
        restApi.startPipeline(pipelineId)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.starting = false;
                ...
            })
            .error(function(data){
                $scope.starting = false;
                ...
            });
    };
```

Comment: Ugh, please replace `pipeline.running == true` with just `pipeline.running`

Comment: Yeah, I normally do that, but trust me, I tried everything to get this to work

Answer (score 0):

Using `ng-show` might be the nicer way:

```
<md-button  ng-click="startPipeline(pipeline._id)" class="md-icon-button md-raised" ng-show="starting || pipeline.running">
```

If you just use the variables **starting** or **pipeline.running**, you do not need to compare their values to `true` or `false`.

Use `var` for `true` and `!var` for `false`.

By the way: if the button does not show/hide by setting the value in your controller, inform your app about the changes with `$scope.$apply();`